# Which design pattern to use for making Pizza

Tags: design-patterns

I want to make a small application which will return me a pizza based on the inputs given.
I want to make a medium size pizza with different inputs 
1. like white dough or brown dough 2. cheese toppings of different types, say white or brown cheese 3. different toppings of onions or tomato or mushrooms

So how do we decide which pattern to choose here, Builder or Decorator?
I feel we can use builder pattern to make pizza first and then one we can use decorator pattern and decorate the pizza based on the different toppings we choose.Am I correct in this understanding?
As I understand, decorator pattern is used to decorate any already existing object. To create this existing object, we would use builder pattern first.

Comment: Design patterns are workarounds for deficiencies in programming languages, so which language are you using?

Comment: Is the user the cook or the customer?

Comment: You also need an efficient design pattern for eating it: http://www.strauss.za.com/sla/sla_pizza.asp (SCNR)

Comment: I m using Java and I am a customer here. I feel tht builder pattern can be used since the ingredients can be changed depending on the pizza type.

Answer (score 2):

Creational Patterns is not what you want here:  You have just one type of object: Pizza.  So both the Factory and Builder patterns will not do.

As per Wikipedia:

> **Decorator** pattern allows a user to add new functionality to an
>   existing object without altering its structure. This type of design
>   pattern comes under structural pattern as this pattern acts as a
>   wrapper to existing class.

The Decorator pattern is clearly what you need.

Comment: No. The decorator pattern adds functionality this is true but the pizza works the same way either with onions or with out, no extra functionality needed.

Comment: I disagree.  "ingredients" **is** "functionality".

Comment: I very interested in how one would implement this with the pizza example. Could you update your answer by adding a java example?

Comment: from Wikipedia:Decorator_pattern: ... "each time adding a new functionality to the overridden method(s)..." In my understanding functionality in the scope of the wiki article means "methods"!

Comment: I would agree to use decorator. You essentially can abstract out those setX to setIngredient(). Essentially you can just decorate the "pizza" with an unlimited number of ingredients and never alter anything involving the pizza code.

Answer (score 2):

**All examples are written in Java**

*TLTR: scroll down to the Builder pattern*

#### Decorator pattern (Do not use it in this case)

The decorator pattern would be used for example if you have a class which represents a Rectangle. The Rectangle class has only one method which calculates the perimeter. Now you want to add a method to the Rectangle to calculate the area. The problem is that you can not nor want to edit the class Rectangle so you create a new class MySuperDuperRectangle like:

The Perimeter interface:

```
interface Perimeter{
    public int perimeter();
}
```

The Rectangle which we can not change for some reason

```
class Rectange implements perimeter{
    private int a, b;

    public Rectange(int a, int b){
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public int getA(){
        return a;
    }
    public int getB(){
        return b;
    }

    public int perimeter(){
        return 2 * a + 2 * b;
    }

}
```

The decorated Rectangle:

```
class MySuperDuperRectange implements perimeter{
    private Rectange r;

    public MySuperDuperRectange(Rectange r){
        this.r = r;
    }

    public int perimeter(){
        return r.perimeter();
    }

    public float area(){
        return r.getA() * r.getB();
    }

}
```

#### Builder pattern (I would use it in this case)

I would go with the Builder pattern because the task is `building` a pizza.

The Builder pattern is used to build something which afterwords exists as is (and which should not be altered at any time).

A basic implementation of the PizzaBuiler could look like this:

Dough enum:

```
enum Dough{
    WHITE, BROWN
}
```

Cheese enum:

```
enum Cheese{
    WHITE, BROWN
}
```

Toppings enum:

```
enum Topping{
    Kittens, Onions, Salami
}
```

The yummi Pizza:

```
class Pizza{

    private Dough dough;
    private Cheese cheese;
    private HashSet<Topping> toppings;

    private Pizza(Dough dough, Cheese cheese, HashSet<Topping> toppings){
        this.dough = dough;
        this.cheese = cheese;
        this.toppings = toppings;
    }

    //add some getters

}
```

The PizzaBuilder:

```
class PizzaBuilder{

    private Dough dough;
    private Cheese cheese;
    private HashSet<Topping> toppings = new HashSet<Topping>();

    public PizzaBuilder(){

    }
    public PizzaBuilder setDough(Dough dough){
        this.dough = dough;
        return this;
    }
    public PizzaBuilder setCheese(Cheese cheese){
        this.cheese = cheese;
        return this;
    }
    public PizzaBuilder addTopping(Topping topping){
        this.toppings.add(topping);
        return this;
    }
    public Pizza buildPizza(){
        return new Pizza(this.dough, this.cheese, this.toppings);
    }

}
```

Now we are going to create the pizza:

```
Pizza myPizza = new PizzaBuilder()
        .setDough(Dough.WHITE)
        .setCheese(Cheese.WHITE)
        .addTopping(Topping.Kittens)
        .addTopping(Topping.Salami)
        .buildPizza();
```

as you can see creating a new pizza is very strait forward and does no require you to write a new class for every possible pizza on earth ;)

Reference implementation: [Builder Pattern](https://ideone.com/YeKYcp)

Answer (score 1):

You can go ahead with Builder pattern, pass dough, toppings of your choice while building up your pizza object, decorator pattern is not required here:

Example of Builder Pattern, Something like this:

```
package com.builder.pattern;
```

public class Pizza {

```
boolean isCheesy;
boolean isTomato;
boolean isMaxican;

public Pizza(PizzaBuilder pizzaBuilder) {
    this.isCheesy = pizzaBuilder.isCheesy;
    this.isTomato = pizzaBuilder.isTomato;
    this.isMaxican = pizzaBuilder.isMaxican;
}

static class PizzaBuilder {

    boolean isCheesy;
    boolean isTomato;
    boolean isMaxican;

    public Pizza build() {
        return new Pizza(this);
    }

    public PizzaBuilder setCheese(boolean isCheesy) {
        this.isCheesy = isCheesy;
        return this;
    }

    public PizzaBuilder setTomato(boolean isTomato) {
        this.isTomato = isTomato;
        return this;
    }

    public PizzaBuilder setMaxican(boolean isMaxican) {
        this.isMaxican = isMaxican;
        return this;
    }
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Pizza [isCheesy=" + isCheesy + ", isTomato=" + isTomato + ", isMaxican=" + isMaxican + "]";
}
```

}

Prepare Pizza as below:

```
Pizza pizza = new Pizza.PizzaBuilder().setCheese(false).setTomato(true).setMaxican(true).build();
    System.out.println(pizza);
```

Or like this

```
Pizza pizza = new Pizza.PizzaBuilder().setMaxican(true).build();
System.out.println(pizza);
```